# riverpod: Pattern for dealing with loading AsyncValue inside an Provider or FutureProvider?

Tags: riverpod

The question is what to return in case an inner provider is loading.

```
final myProvider = Provider<int>((ref) {
  final myAsyncValue = ref.watch(someFutureProvider);
  return myAsyncValue.when(data: compute_something,
  loading: what_to_do_here,
  error: (_, __) => throw Exception());
}
```

And what about if `myProvider` is a `FutureProvider`?

Apologies if I am fundamentally misunderstanding riverpod.

thx

Comment: i really dont understand your question though

Comment: you can simply return 0 for loading or u can simply make the return type casting to int? so that when you are loading asyncValue returns null and also error returns null

Comment: That is basically what I am doing right now - I thought there might be a more idiomatic way to handle this

Comment: i guess thats it then

Comment: i wrote some code down, but i don't want to put it here so that StackOverflow will rate me down